# Why can't I read deno proxy environment variable on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, proxy, deno

I'm on Windows 10 and read the deno manual that says you need to set up the environment variable `HTTPS_PROXY` so that `fetch()` will use the proxy.

I did so by doing

```js
Deno.env.set('HTTP_PROXY', 'https://138.68.60.8:3128/');
Deno.env.set('HTTPS_PROXY', 'https://138.68.60.8:3128/');
```

yet the fetch still fetches without the proxy. Instead, if I set up a proxy in the Windows system setting, the fetch will use it. Which doesn't solve the problem though as I am trying to a proxy list rolling.

Comment: I've answered the question using a different method. If this needs to be done in environment variables for some reason, I would take a guess and say that Deno reads the environment variables once at the start of runtime (instead of every fetch requests). This would mean that'd you have to set the environment variables before the script even runs. This can be done through: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Deno source code, their own tests use a different method that  I couldn't find in the documentation:

```js
// Copyright 2018-2022 the Deno authors. All rights reserved. MIT license.

const client = Deno.createHttpClient({
  proxy: {
    url: "http://localhost:4555",
    basicAuth: { username: "username", password: "password" },
  },
});

const res = await fetch(
  "http://localhost:4545/045_mod.ts",
  { client },
);
console.log(`Response http: ${await res.text()}`);

client.close();
```

For your specific use case, I would setup a http client:

```js
const client = Deno.createHttpClient({
  proxy: {
    url: "https://138.68.60.8:3128",
  },
});
```

And then use that client on your fetch requests:

```js
fetch("https://example.com", { client });
```